# How to approach this kind of (conditional) probability problem?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Edit: I would appreciate *any* kind of input.

This is an old homework task I'm still not able to solve:

> A DNA sample was taken from a murder scene. Statistically, only 1 in a million people is a match. However, the test used is erroneous in $0.001\%$ of the cases. One of  $20$ tested suspects tests positively. What is the probability that the one with the positive test result is not guilty (the actual source of the sample)?

Additional conditions: The suspects are the only possible murderers. The source of the DNA is in fact the murderer, and no one else was involved in the murder.

So using Bayes' theorem, the probability of not being a match despite a positive test result in general is

$$P(¬M|+)=\frac{P(¬M)\cdot P(+|¬M)}{P(+)}$$

$$=\frac{\frac{999999}{1000000}\cdot \frac{1}{100000}}{\frac{999999}{1000000}\cdot \frac{1}{100000}+\frac{1}{1000000}\cdot\frac{99999}{100000}}=\frac{111111}{122222}\approx 0.90909$$

Now how do I proceed? Can I calculate the probability for one of the others to test negatively despite being a match (the source), and then calculate the probability for the remaining 18 to test correctly (negative), and then multiply everything together? The result is *tiny*, which at least makes sense intuitively.

Comment: "Additional conditions: The suspects are the only possible murderers" Sorry but this condition is quite unrealistic and it changes completely the answer, so I must ask whether you added it yourself or if it was in the original exercise?

Comment: @Did It was in fact included (because of "investigation"). In class we discussed the task, but the professor wasn't very interested so that he just talked it down and we didn't get to see a complete solution.